# it's about discord Self hosting

Tags: discord.js

I have 2 bots and I want put them online but I use visual code studio to put it online(in the terminal of folder i just write node . and he start)and if I open other bot folder the 1 bot just turn off, if you can help me with this I appreciate it, and approving that I'm here my bot after some time don't work the commands, i need put some refresh time?In some scripts of fivem you need put one restart time to work the scripts like 24 Hours but I'm new in discord.js and i don't know if i need do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the Command Line (Windows), or the Terminal (macOS & linux), that is built into visual studio, you can open the command line or terminal outside of visual studio, and navigate to the directory.

---

Windows:

Press the `Windows Key` + `R` to open the "Run" window. Then type `cmd` into the input, and press run. Once you are in the command prompt, you can navigate into the folder where you bot is in, by using the `cd` command. You can, for example, type `cd Desktop` to go to your desktop, and then the `dir` command to see all files and directories (folders) on your desktop. You can use these commands to get to the directory that your `app.js` or `index.js` files is in.

---

macOS or Linux:

To open the terminal, you can go to the launchpad (macOS), or the respective linux alternative, and find the terminal application. Then you can navigate into the folder where you bot is in, by using the `cd` command. You can, for example, type `cd Desktop` to go to your desktop, and then the `ls` command to see all files and directories (folders) on your desktop. You can use these commands to get to the directory that your `app.js` or `index.js` files is in.

---

Then you can run your command to start the bot, using the normal `node yourBotFile.js` to start the bot. You can repeat the steps again for the second bot and run them at the same time.